# laravel 5 - not sure what kind of relationship I need between two eloquent models

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I'm having an issue trying to determine the relationship for the given scenario:

```
Table `appointments`
    id
    service_id
    client_id
    ...

Table `clients`
    id
    ...

Table `services`
    id
    ...
```

What I want is to show all clients for a given service.  I initially thought it might be a `hasManyThrough` IE a service has many clients through the appointment table, but I can't seem to dial that one in correct.  Can anyone give me some advice about the best way to structure this relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like clients have many services and services have many clients. Many to many relation looks good here. The appointments table would be the pivot table with any extra info if needed.

Comment: Don't know how I missed that.  Great explanation.  Thanks!